# How to retrieve the latest record that has been added to a set?

Tags: java, hibernate, set, hibernate-mapping

I have a class called MyClass which keeps a set of student objects as member.

Currently I can pass the id of required student and retrieve the object but not sure how to retrieve the latest one who has been added.

I am wondering how I can change the code to retrieve the object of last student that was added to the class?

**"I know set does not maintain order, is there any method to retrieve the latest one using hibernate or by comparing the enrolledDate members of student class?"**

**MyClass**

```
import java.util.Set

@Entity
public class MyClass {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   @OneToMany
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   private Set<Student> students;

   ....
}
```

**Student class**

```
@Entity
public class Student {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   private String name;

   @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
   private Date enrolledDate; //I may need to use this date as it is enrollment date but not sure how to retrieve the latest one.
}
```

**Hibernate Code**

```
 MyClass myClass = (MyClass) session.get(MyClass.class, id);

 Iterator<MyClass> it = myClass.getStudents().iterator();

 Student stu = new Student();

 while (it.hasNext()) {
            stu = it.next();
            if (stu.getId() == stuId) {
                        break;
            }
 }

System.err.println("Student name is:" + stu.getName());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay a Set (or some other collection) in Hibernate can be ordered in one of two ways: using @Sort (in-memory sort) or using @OrderBy (database sort).

As @OrderBy cannot be used on nested properties (e.g. myclass.student.dateEnrolled) you will need to use @Sort.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Sort.html

http://eubauer.de/kingsware/2011/03/15/ordering-collections-with-jpa/

All you need to do then is:

```
@OneToMany
@Sort(...)
private Set<Student> students; //note leave as Set
```

If the types in the Set implement Comparable and this is the Order you want you can specify SortType.NATURAL. Otherwise you can specify a Comparator to handle the sorting.

Hibernate will ensure the Set passed in is sorted. If we assume this Set implements the NavigableSet Interface (and you would need to check this) then you can use the methods of that Interface to find the latest:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html

Note that if there were a large number of students and you only ever wanted the latest then this is a sub-optimal solution as all Students will be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that the `id` of `student` is `auto increment` you can use `TreeSet` so that the recent `Student` will be right most element in the `TreeSet` (write your `compareTo()` on top of `id`).You can use `last()` of `TreeSet` which will give you the latest.

Even instead of `id` you can use anything that is ascending order (write compareTo() accordingly ),and put `student` into `TreeSet` and fetch `last()` i.e. recent `student` object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed it to treeset but it returns SEVERE:   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @ OneToMany, @ ManyToMany or @ CollectionOfElements

Comment: @J888 you will have to implement Comparable for Student and override compareTo() method.

Comment: but the error is coming from hibernate that is not considering it as a collection.

Comment: @J888 can you put your code? i am not getting what r u trying to say.

Comment: I'd changed type of student to TreeSet<Student> students and have ran the application which ran into the above mentioned error.

Comment: `private Set<Student> students;` the instance of this should be `TreeSet` and you Student class should implement Comparable.

Comment: I did that but still runs into following error  org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @ OneToMany, @ ManyToMany or @ CollectionOfElements

Comment: @J888 i don't have much idea about hibernate and also it's different question. Your original question's solution i have given.

Comment: Thanks but your solution does not solve the problem as I can not avoid hibernate, I am looking for a solution that support hibernate. Thats why hibernate is tagged.

Answer (score 0):

Set does not maintains the order, you can try other Collections like LinkedHashSet which stores elements in insertion order or a PriorityQueue that provides access from both ends.